# Destroying Activity or application itself from another application

Tags: android

I have two applications. One is a receiver and its starting my application. It works fine. Now i want destroy my application from the receiver itself. Is that possible ? Please note that these are my own application

Comment: do you want some solutions, ig would be good if you can post code snippet of ur app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible but the activity has to finish itself using the `finish()`-method.

You can register an activity to a receiver using `registerReceiver(..)` and handle your logic in your activity. Don't forget to `unregisterReceiver(...)` inside the OnDestroy.

Example:

```
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

@Overrride
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
  filter.addAction(...);

  mReceiver= new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      // implement logic
      finish();
    }
  }
  registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant directly control the lifecycle of one activity from another actvity
alternates to this could be :

- you can set a [timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) in the new activity, if you want to end it after a certain amount of time, and call `finish()' in`run()`
- you can `finish()` the new activity on some events with [EventListeners](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/EventListener.html)